# Django Admin: how to display additional fields for users?

Tags: django, user-interface, django-admin, django-templates

Create some additional fields for users using the example found on page Django "Methods to create user profiles" which worked satisfactorily, but the problem I have is when you want to insert these new data to the user because I see from the admin and the other solution I find is not from a form, but I actually prefer the idea of ​​it from the Django admin to maintain the status of administration.

Thus it was that insert additional fields to the user model:

```
## User Additional Fields
User.add_to_class ('nit' models.IntegerField (max_length = 20, null = True))
User.add_to_class ('company', models.CharField (max_length = 30, null = True))
User.add_to_class ('address', models.CharField (max_length = 30, null = True))
User.add_to_class ('city', models.CharField (max_length = 10, null = True))
User.add_to_class ('phone', models.CharField (max_length = 10, null = True))
User.add_to_class ('Mobile', models.CharField (max_length = 10, null = True))
```

On the other hand the functions of "Permissions" in the same user like me to remove it because it is unnecessary for the platform this information and that additional fields remain in "Personal info" all being in this way the administrator:

**Personal info**

First name:

Last name:

E-mail address:

Nit:

company:

address:

city:

Phone:

Mobile:

Can you help me see how I can get these new fields in the admin Django1.4? I need help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is edit your UserProfile in the admin along with the user? If so, try putting the following in an admin.py file in whatever app you've defined the UserProfile:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from myapp.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileFormSet(inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.can_delete = False

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    formset = UserProfileFormSet

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]


# Re-register altered UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: for `OneToOneField`, there is no need to explicitly specify `max_num=1` and `extra=0` in the InlineModelAdmin

Comment: to see if I understand, I create a file called admin.py (This I have already created) in my mind if you create models to the admin, but I have I have problems, first I did was extend the fields in the database the default User that do not create a UserProfile model, this is another method? I suddenly have to do it that way. the idea is to make visible the add_to_class that was done to the User in the Admin.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're talking about sorry, but if you're thinking about extending the User model instead of creating a UserProfile class, I'd say you're asking for trouble. I've seen it done and it caused all sorts of issues. You can read about UserProfiles here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users